# How can I change the Axios responseURL when connecting a Vue.js frontend with a Node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios, frontend, backend

I am trying to connect a Vue.js frontend to a Node.js backend using Axios. I followed tutorials online and have the following code snippets:

In backend, I have the following Node.js code snippet to post to `localhost:5000/signup` :

```
app.post("/signup", (req, res) =>{ // receive form data from signup
  console.log("Hello");
})
```

I am listening to port 5000:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port", server.address().port);
});
```

Frontend code snippets look something like this:

```
  methods: {
    submit() {
      this.$v.$touch();
      axios.post("/api/signup", {
        fname: this.fname,
        lname: this.lname,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        gender: 'Male',
        dob: this.dob,
      }).then((res) => {
        if(res.data.msg === "Email exists"){
          console.log("Email exists")
        }
        else{
          this.$router.push({ path: './browsing' });
        }
      })
      // .catch(()=>{
      //   alert("Something Went Wrong");
      // })      
      

    },
    clear() {
      this.$v.$reset()
      this.name = ''
      this.email = ''
      this.select = null
      this.checkbox = false
    },
  }
```

I expected the Axios responseURL in the console to send me to localhost:5000/signup and print "Hello" but I have the following error message:

```
responseURL
: 
"http://localhost:8081/api/signup"
```

It sends me to localhost:8081 which is the default port for Vue and DOESN'T PRINT ANYTHING. What could be the reason for this? And how can I make my responseURL localhost:5000/signup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around, I found that the problem was me not requiring "cors" in the backend file.

All I added was:

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```